# Can I use fixed parameter settings for one component when using GridSearchCV with pipeline？

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I am trying to first apply PCA to the original data, and then use decision tree for classification.

For PCA, I just want to fix the n_components, and for decision tree, I am using GridSearchCV to find best hyperparameter settings.

How do I make sure that n_components does not change? Can I fix it when I am defining PCA in the pipline, and does not mention any setting for PCA in param_grid of GridSearchCV?

Or shall I fix it in the param_grid of GridSearchCV like 'PCA__n_components':[5]?

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to perform this operation.

1. Initialize the Transformer/Estimator with the hyperparameter:

   ```
   pipe = Pipeline(
       steps=[('pca', PCA(n_components=2)),
              ('clf', DecisionTreeClassifier())])
   ```
2. Fix the hyperparameter in the param_grid:

   ```
   param_grid = {
   'pca__n_components': [2]
   }

   grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid)
   ```

**Notes**:
The dimension of the PCA is an important parameter to fine tuned your model. An optimal `n_components` will certainly boost the performance of your model while reducing its complexity.